# Windows script/application to convert GPX to KML?

Tags: kml, windows, gpx

[OSRM](http://map.project-osrm.org/) seems to have everything I need to draw bicycle routes, but it only exports routes as GPX while the smartphone application I use only supports KML.

Does someone know if there's a Windows script or application that I could use to easily convert GPX to KML?

I know the [Gpx2Kml](http://gpx2kml.com/) site, but I'd like a one-click solution.