# Command-line utility to convert GPX into KML?

Tags: kml, windows, gpx

I use [Cycle.travel](http://cycle.travel/) to draw cycling routes. However, the Android application I use on my smartphone only supports KML.

As an alternative to GPSVisualizer, I tried the command-line utility GPSBabel, but, besides turning a compact 5K GPX into a much bigger 80K KML, the route is displayed as a long series of waypoints instead of a simple line:

[image]

Does someone know of an alternative **command-line utility** to GPSBabel?

Here's a sample from the source GPX file and the KML generated by GPSBabel:

GPX

```
<trk>
<name>ACTIVE LOG</name>
<trkseg>
<trkpt lat="48.81569" lon="2.31610" />
<trkpt lat="48.81579" lon="2.31590" />
…
<trkpt lat="48.75456" lon="2.18915" />
<trkpt lat="48.75510" lon="2.18814" />
</trkseg>
</trk>
```

KML from GpsBabel

```
…
    <LookAt>
      <longitude>2.252120</longitude>
      <latitude>48.785320</latitude>
      <range>15131.199708</range>
    </LookAt>
    <!-- Normal track style -->
    <Style id="track_n">
      <IconStyle>
        <scale>.5</scale>
        <Icon>
          <href>http://earth.google.com/images/kml-icons/track-directional/track-none.png</href>
        </Icon>
      </IconStyle>
      <LabelStyle>
        <scale>0</scale>
      </LabelStyle>
    </Style>
…
…
<![CDATA[<table>
<tr><td><b>Distance</b> 9.8 mi </td></tr>
</table>]]>
</description>
        <Folder>
          <name>Points</name>
          <Placemark>
            <name>ACTIVE LOG-0</name>
            <snippet/>
            <description><![CDATA[
<table>
<tr><td>Longitude: 2.316100 </td></tr>
<tr><td>Latitude: 48.815690 </td></tr>
<tr><td>Heading: 2.0 </td></tr>
</table>
…
        <Placemark>
          <name>Path</name>
          <styleUrl>#lineStyle</styleUrl>
          <LineString>
            <tessellate>1</tessellate>
            <coordinates>
2.316100,48.815690
2.315900,48.815790
…
2.189150,48.754560
2.188140,48.755100
</coordinates>
          </LineString>
        </Placemark>
      </Folder>
    </Folder>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

Comment: ogr2ogr http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html with GPX driver http://www.gdal.org/drv_gpx.html and KML driver http://www.gdal.org/drv_kml.html. GPSBabel probably can do that as well http://www.gpsbabel.org/.

Comment: I use this site http://gpx2kml.com/ for conversion of this kind of data. It works very well.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a *command-line utility*. GPSVisualizer is another web-based solution that works well.

Comment: Right, that is why I posted as a comment instead of answer, I have added your question as a favorite, because I would also be interested in learning about a cmd line utility for this purpose.

Comment: What outcome do you expect? There are a number of tools, e.g. [GDAL/OGR](http://gdal.org/) but their outcome will also be a series of waypoints, since that is also the way your input GPX file is organized with its `trkpnt`s.

Comment: The key here is way*points*, they are seen as a group of points and converted to KML as such. In reality they should be vertices on a linestring (see the KML). Given the format is TEXT it wouldn't be too hard to create a tool to convert GPX into KML but it would take quite a bit of typing to insert all the header/footer and then *somehow* detect when the tracklog stops and restarts. I don't know of any pre-built utility that does this... this might be a good time to learn python.

Comment: You're probably looking for [tag:ogr2ogr]. See the duplicate [Windows script/application to convert GPX to KML?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/118623/windows-script-application-to-convert-gpx-to-kml) (this question is phrased better, the answers over there are applicable).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. GPSBabel works ok, but requires the following switch before creating the KML output: -o kml,points=0

Comment: @Gulbahar you should post this comment as an answer, it is the solution to the problem but buried in the question's comments

Answer (score 2):

GPSBabel will do pretty much any of that. HERE is the [Link!](http://www.gpsbabel.org/)

From the documentation ...

> What is GPSBabel?
>
> GPSBabel converts waypoints, tracks, and routes between popular GPS receivers such as Garmin or Magellan and mapping programs like Google Earth or Basecamp. Literally hundreds of GPS receivers and programs are supported. It also has powerful manipulation tools for such data. such as filtering duplicates points or simplifying tracks. It has been downloaded and used tens of millions of times since it was first created in 2001, so it's stable and truste

Answer (score 2):

You can install the latest GDAL binaries from http://www.gisinternals.com/sdk (if it is not down) or [OSGEO4W](http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/wiki) and run ogr2ogr with a batch file containing

```
ogr2ogr -f KML testout.kml testin.gpx
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm lost at what I should download to run "ogr2ogr" on a 32-bit Windows 7 host.

Comment: From gisinternals, you can take a successful build (with green status) of the stable or release version for your OS, then take the zip from top of the list, and extract it to a folder and run SDKshell.bat.

Comment: These days the easiest route to get `ogr2ogr` is to install Qgis. After that it lives in `<install-dir>\QGIS 3.10\bin` (on Windows, not sure where for 'nix and mac).